# Is this possible to fix these issues in roku?

Tags: android, roku, brightscript

Im working on a roku app using scene graph component. I am facing many issues like...

1. During video buffering i want to pause video. Im using this code but not working

   video.control = "pause"
2. During video buffering a blank screen is displaying. I want to show last video image instead of blank screen.
3. I want to show dialog box to check internet connection on splash screen.
4. Is this possible to use BrightScript component like "roImageCanvas" or "roListScreen" in scene graph component?

Since Im working first time on brightscript so i don't know does roku supports this type of job or not.

Please suggest any ideas to fix the above issues.

Thank you

Comment: Everything is possible mate

Comment: Can you suggest how to do?

Comment: @Kurlicue - wrong! #4 Isn't.

Comment: Can anyone suggest any point how to do?

Comment: #1. Show some code. I think what you want is possible, but I'm not totally clear on what you mean.  
  
#2. Maybe? You might be able to pull the image out of trick mode and post it. I'd have to take a look. You could probably put a poster over the video and listen for buffering if you had the image.

Comment: 3. Possible. Check the connection in main before you show anything. Pass the information to the component.  
  
4. No. You can close the scene graph screen and show another component, but that's it. Honestly, it doesn't matter since you can easily simulate anything in the vanilla Roku library in scene graph using things like rowList and Poster.

Comment: @Morgan LaVigne  #1. My requirment is this when video is buffering then pause/resume functionality should be work. 
If i use video.control = "stop" then it stopped the buffering but again resume functionality will not work.
#2. Can we pull the image when state is paused or playing of any video? 
#3. I want to show dialog box on splash screen. There is a gap between splash screen and home screen. Dialog box should be open before gap.
I think when we pass the information to the component then home screen will be display.

Answer (score 0):

1) Not sure what's causing it for you, please share the code for better help.

2) I don't think Scene Graph enables you to do that yet! Couldn't find any reference to any such ability.

3) In your main.brs, at the very beginning you can use Dialog node to show a dialog box, to show message or to take input (buttons), and to check for the network you can use the method GetLinkStatus() of the object roDeviceInfo.

4) For all the substtues for Brightscript Components, look up here: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Transitioning+to+Scene+Graph